# Transform rotateZ is happening after animation

Tags: html, css

For some reason my rotateZ is happening after the animation, right now I'm in the early stages of making a hand that opens. The finger is supposed to only change from rotateX to make it look like an actual hand opening which it is doing but the rotateZ again only happens after the animation.

You can view it here (or in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaydiazzz/84Lm4tyv/)):

```css
.zombie {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.zombie .hand {
  border-radius: 35%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
  background-color: #005700;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #005700;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  left: -2.4%;
  bottom: 30%;
  border-top-left-radius: 30%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30%;
  border-radius: 41%;
  transform: rotateZ(20deg);
  animation-name: zombie;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes zombie {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grass"></div>
<div class="zombie">
  <div class="finger one"></div>
  <div class="finger two"></div>
  <div class="finger three"></div>
  <div class="finger four"></div>
  <div class="hand"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the code snippet so we can see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep `rotateZ(20deg)`, try below:

```
@keyframes zombie{
    0% {
        transform: rotateZ(20deg) rotateY(90deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateZ(20deg) rotateY(0deg);
    }
}
```